# ActiveRecord :includes - how to use map with loaded associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

I have a small rails app, and I'm trying to get some order statistics.
So I have an Admin model, and an Order model, with one-to-many association.

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :orders
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :operation
  belongs_to :admin
```

And I'm trying to get specifical orders using this query:

```
admins = Admin.where(...).includes(:orders).where('orders.operation = ?', 'new gifts!')
```

That works just as expected. But when I try to make json using map like that

```
admins.map {|a| [a.name, a.orders.pluck(:operation)]}
```

Rails loads orders again using new query, ignoring already loaded objects.

```
(5.6ms)  SELECT "orders"."operation" FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."admin_id" = 26
(6.8ms)  SELECT "orders"."operation" FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."admin_id" = 24
(2.9ms)  SELECT "orders"."operation" FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."admin_id" = 30
(3.3ms)  SELECT "orders"."operation" FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."admin_id" = 29
(4.8ms)  SELECT "orders"."operation" FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."admin_id" = 27
(3.3ms)  SELECT "orders"."operation" FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."admin_id" = 28
(5.1ms)  SELECT "orders"."operation" FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."admin_id" = 25
```

When I try to use 
loop instead of map, it works as it should:

```
admins.each do |a|
  p a.orders.pluck(:operation)
end
```

this code doesn't load all orders, and prints only those loaded in the first query.
Is it possible to get the same result using map? What are the drawbacks of using loop instead of map?

Comment: what is your Ruby and Rails version?

Comment: I use Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2

Comment: as a general rule when using conditions on the association it is better to use `joins`. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470027/activerecord-cant-use-pluck-after-where-clause-with-eager-loaded-associati). Though the question still remains why it works in `each` and not in `map`

Comment: thank you very much for that, I believe this combined with the answer below will let me out of this trouble. I will update my question as soon as I test it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pluck` should always make a new query to database. Not sure why you think it does not happen in an `each` loop. Maybe you did not see the log because it is in between your prints?

There are 2 possibilities how to avoid additional queries.

1. Since orders are already loaded because you include them, you can do `admins.map {|a| [a.name, a.orders.collect(&:operation)]}`
2. Using joins (see @tihom's comment).

Edit: I just tested the `each`/ `map` behavior and it reloads every time as expected.

Comment: well, I've used .count instead of .pluck and got the same results as in my question, so I beleive it's not the case.

Comment: count behaves the same way, all ActiveRecord::Calculations methods (count, average, minimum, maximum, calculate, sum pluck and ids) perform a new query regardless of what is or is not loaded. You don't have to take my word for it, you can look at Rails code yourself.